# Change the color of footnote marker in LaTeX

Tags: color, footnotes

I'm trying to do up a resume in LaTeX however I'm wanting to use a different color for the footnote markers so that it's clear that they are not part of the normal text.

```
PHP, Java, C\footnote{It has been many years since I've used this in a project}, Python
```

This results in the following, which ends up looking like C^1:
[image: PHP, Java, C^1, Python]

How do I change the font color of the "1" to a light grey so that it's more obvious that it's separate from the main body of text.

Comment: Possibly related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110362 (in his case, "Putting \color{blue} before \begin{document} solved the issue.")

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It all depends on exactly what do you want to colorize since there are three possible elements involved: 1) the mark used in the text to signal the footnote, 2) the mark used at the bottom of the page where the actual footnote text appears, and (possibly) 3) the mark used when cross-referencing the footnote. In the following examples I used the color `red` just to highlight the different results:

A redefinition of `\thefootnote` (like some other answers suggest) will affect all these three elements:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=3cm]{geometry}% just for the example
\usepackage{xcolor}

\renewcommand\thefootnote{\textcolor{red}{\arabic{footnote}}}

\begin{document}

PHP, Java, C\footnote{\label{a}It has been many years since I've used this in a project}, Python

As was mentioned in~\ref{a}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If one only wants to change color to elements 1) and 2) (the marks in the body and in the actual footnote text) but not to 3) (the number used in cross-references), then a redefinition of `\@makefnmark` will be needed:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=3cm]{geometry}% just for the example
\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@makefnmark{\hbox{\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\color{red}\@thefnmark}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

PHP, Java, C\footnote{\label{a}It has been many years since I've used this in a project}, Python

As was mentioned in~\ref{a}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Finally, if the change of color must affect only the mark used in the body of the document without affecting the mark used in the footnote text or the number used in cross-references, then redefinitions of `\@makefnmark`, and `\@makefntext` will be needed:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=3cm]{geometry}% just for the example
\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@makefnmark{\hbox{\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\color{red}\@thefnmark}}}
\renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{%
  \parindent 1em\noindent
            \hb@xt@1.8em{%
                \hss\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}}#1}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

PHP, Java, C\footnote{\label{a}It has been many years since I've used this in a project}, Python

As was mentioned in~\ref{a}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, well you gave me a lot more than I was looking for. Thank you for the amount of effort you put into your answer. You not only answered my question but I feel your answer will also be very useful for others with similar questions, so I am selecting this as the correct answer as well as a +1. Thank you.

Comment: How can this be "transfered" to the endnotes?  ie, when using `\usepackage{endnotes}` and `\let\footnote=\endnote`?

Comment: @NikosAlexandris Feel free to open a follow-up question.

Comment: Follow-up question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/272142/change-color-of-endnotes-markers

Answer (score 9):

Another possibility is:

```
C{\color{Gray}\footnote{TextOfTheFootnote}}
```

Comment: This also works for table notes \color{red}{\textbf{\tnote{1}}} for the threeparttable package.

Comment: Your comment is very useful for single use cases, like highlighting only one footnote. 
I actually use `C{\textcolor{Gray}{\footnote{TextOfTheFootnote}}} moreText` so that `moreText` coming after isn't grey as well.

Comment: Any idea why this doesn't work in beamer?

Comment: sorry, haven't used latex in ages...

Answer (score 4):

In preamble:

```
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}

\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\textcolor{Gray}{\arabic{footnote}}}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
\usepackage{hyperref} % IN THE PREAMBLE
\hypersetup{linkcolor = red}
```

Just don't forget to change `linkcolor` back if you don't want to leave as it is

```
\hypersetup{linkcolor = black}
```

This also works with `\footnotemark` color change.

Comment: In my case I need `\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}` otherwise it will fail silently.

Answer (score 0):

Using the enotez package this works for me.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{enotez}
\let\footnote\endnote

\renewcommand*\enotezwritemark[1]{\hypersetup{linkcolor=blue}\textsuperscript{#1}\hypersetup{linkcolor=red}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    x = 1
    \label{eq1}
\end{equation}

This is equation \ref{eq1}

The color of a footnote should be different\footnote{in fact it should be blue}.

\printendnotes

\end{document}
```

[image: output]