# How can I make footnote text color match body text color?

Tags: color, footnotes

How can I modify the following code to also make the footnote text blue (globally, for all footnotes), like the body text?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}
\color{blue}

This is sample text.\footnote{See page 1.}

\end{document}
```

I'm weaving Rnw files with `knitr` and typesetting LaTeX into PDF using `pdfLaTeX`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: @azetina that doesn't fix the footnotemarker as the color comes too late

Comment: For what it's worth: [KOMA-Script](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) classes offer `\addtokomafont{footnote}{\color{blue}}` and `\addtokomafont{footnoterule}{\color{blue}}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Open the class file you use, e.g., `article.cls` and search for the definition of the command `\@makefntext`. Copy that to the preamble of your document and modify it to add some color command to it, e.g., for the article class:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\@makefntext[1]{%
    \parindent 1em%
    \noindent
    \color{blue}%                        % <----
    \hb@xt@1.8em{\hss\@makefnmark}#1}
\makeatother
```

However, I guess you aren't just interested in getting the footnotes in the right color, but perhaps all of the text? If so then there is a much simpler way: put your `\color{blue}` before `\begin{document}` then blue will be used whenever `\normalcolor` is called and that means in `\marginpar`, `\footnote`...

Comment: I wish one did not have to hack into the original definition of core commands for simple changes like changing color or style. I completely understand why this is the case (limited CPU resources when LaTeX started), but wish backward compatibility did not have such a huge price.

Comment: @Aditya you don't really, you only need to if you stick to the basic compatibility classes (which most people do) ... perhaps we should put out a really comprehensive class compared to memoir or others and stick it into the base distribution

Comment: I believe that introducing an official (i.e., something in `base`) comprehensive class (and, of course, updating all introductory guides to ask users to use such a class) will go a long with in getting rid of the misconception that LaTeX is hard to use.

Comment: @FrankMittelbach Putting `\color{blue}` before `\begin{document}` solved the issue. Thank you.

Comment: @AdamSmith if one or the other answer solve sour problem you may want to checkmark it to indicate this

Comment: @FrankMittelbach Regarding the two other provided answers, there was a small issue with one of them as described in my comment, and for the other, I am not currently using ConTeXt. I didn't know, however, that selecting multiple correct answers was an option, so thanks for the tip.

Comment: @AdamSmith not sure but I guess you can select only one so you probably need to choose and pick what best answers your question (if you are satisfied) but it helps to understand that you are not any longer looking for further/better answers

Answer (score 4):

For comparison, ConTeXt provides a `\setupnotation[footnote]` command that can be used to change the color of the footnote (and the footnote symbol).

```
\setuppapersize[S3]

\setupcolors[textcolor=blue]
\setupnotation[footnote][color=blue, headcolor=blue]

\starttext
This is sample text.\footnote{See page 1.}
\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: yep clearly better interface compared to what was designed a decade or two earlier.

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor, footmisc, bigfoot}
\def\footnotelayout{\color{blue}}
\begin{document}
\color{blue}

This is sample text.\footnote{See page 1.}

\end{document}
```

bigfoot, because it deals with the colour stack in case of page breaks. footmisc, because it offers the command footnotelayout. And this answer comes from robin fairbairns, see here: http://newsgroups.derkeiler.com/Archive/Comp/comp.text.tex/2008-05/msg01367.html

Comment: I tried this first and it almost did what I needed, but the color of the actual number in the footnote text was left unchanged. Thanks for the input and the package suggestions.

Comment: I haven't got time right now, but search this forum for colour and footnote and you'll get quite a lot suggestions how to get the marks colored as well.