# Change color of endnotes markers

Tags: color, endnotes

Following the question [Change the color of footnote marker in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26693/8272), how can the color be "transfered" to endnotes markers? Specifically, when using

```
\usepackage{endnotes}
\let\footnote=\endnote?
```

Is there special attention required to when using XeLaTeX?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion the best option is to redefine `\@makeenmark`, which has the advantage of fixing the clumsy definition made by `endnotes`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=5cm]{geometry}% just for the example
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{endnotes}

%%% Customizations
\let\footnote\endnote

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@makeenmark{%
  \textsuperscript{\normalfont\textcolor{red}{\@theenmark}}%
}
\newcommand{\uncolormarkers}{%
  \renewcommand\@makeenmark{%
    \textsuperscript{\normalfont\@theenmark}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

PHP, Java, C\footnote{It has been many years since I've
used this in a project}, Python

\uncolormarkers
\theendnotes

\end{document}
```

Just remove `\uncolormarkers` if you want the markers to be red also in the end notes section.

[image]

---

This is a possible way using `enotez`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=5cm]{geometry}% just for the example
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{enotez}

%%% Customizations
\let\footnote\endnote
\NewDocumentCommand{\colorendnotemark}{m}{%
  \textsuperscript{\textcolor{red}{#1}}%
}

\setenotez{
  mark-cs = \colorendnotemark
}

\begin{document}

PHP, Java, C\footnote{It has been many years since I've
used this in a project}, Python

\printendnotes

\end{document}
```

[image: With enotez]

Comment: Why is the definition made by `endnotes` clumsy?

Comment: @NikosAlexandris Because it is `\def\@makeenmark{\hbox{\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@theenmark}}}` and it should be `\def\@makeenmark{\textsuperscript{\normalfont\@theenmark}}`

Comment: Suggestion for improvement to the `endnotes` authors?

Comment: @NikosAlexandris Maybe. It's possibly better using `enotez`.

Comment: I already switched to `enotez` before attempting the provided solution for the asked question. Confirming both solutions.

Comment: Plus, `enotez` works with `fnpct`, no need to work-around the incompatibility between `footmisc` and `hyperref`. Awesome! (see `enotez`' manual and 3rd solution in http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/71015/8272)

Answer (score 2):

Since you didn't reveal which case (of different options Gonzalo discusses in the linked answer) you want, here is a starter:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=3cm]{geometry}% just for the example
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\let\footnote=\endnote

\renewcommand{\makeenmark}{\hbox{\color{red}$^\theenmark$}}

% or
% \makeatletter
% \renewcommand{\makeenmark}{\textcolor{red}{\@makeenmark}}
% \makeatother

\begin{document}

PHP, Java, C\footnote{\label{a}It has been many years since I've used this in a project}, Python

As was mentioned in~\ref{a}

\theendnotes

\end{document}
```

[image]