# Change color of all footnote elements at once

Tags: color, luatex, footnotes

I'm using a specific shade of grey for my overall font color, but when I insert a `\footnote`, it appears in black. How can I have all the elements of it in my actual text color? Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\begin{document}
\color{gray!80}
Here is some text with a footnote\footnote{... which should be grey!}
\end{document}
```

[Change the color of footnote marker in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26693/change-the-color-of-footnote-marker-in-latex) is only for the footnote marker and I can't get all the other elements to change color, especially the rule. So I thought there should be a single command to have everything changed at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happened because of `\normalcolor` tag which is used inside `footnote` defintion, following tags may helps you:

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\begin{document}
\color{gray!80}
\definecolor{Normalcolor}{gray}{0.8}
\newcommand{\splcolor}{\color{Normalcolor}}
\let\normalcolor\splcolor
Here is some text with a footnote\footnote{... which should be grey!}
\end{document}
```